# How to load an xaml file/workflow in UIPath when a value is selected from a dropdown then a button is clicked

Tags: uipath, rpa, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-activity

I have installed UIPath.Form.Activities and used Create Form activity. I then created a form with a dropdown and a submit button. On the dropdown, there are two values: Process 1 and Process 2 as below:
[image]

Each process has a separate workflow on my project. I would like to run each process (xaml file) based on the selected item on the dropdown list after I clicked the submit/run button. Anyone know how to? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use a string argument `SelectedProcess` in the FormFieldCollection of the form activity and map it to a workflow variable.
2. Map this `SelectedProcess` with your select dropdown.
3. On submitting the form, you'll get the selected process named in the workflow variable you would have created.